# Airtable Form to Discord Webhooks through Zapier

Tags: discord.js, webhooks, zapier, airtable

I'm relatively new to Discord Webhooks, Airtable, and Zapier.

I have an Airtable form that accepts parameters that I'm planning to display on one of my Discord Server's text channels.

I have managed to do that easily with Zapier with their Airtable to Discord zap and it looked like this:

[Zapier Result Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzORP.png) (I have no permission yet to post a photo, forgive me)

However, I want the information to be an embedded message and would look something like this:

[Expected Embedded message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGq95.png) (again apologies for providing a link only)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the no-code swwweeetness! Now get ready to code a little bit

Use a [POST](https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations) action in `Zapier` to send properly formatted JSON to create these neat cards. You will replace any `static` values with the `dynamic` values from `Airtable`. Create your Embed Message using the visualizer below and then copy/paste into the body of the POST.

[Embed-Visualizer](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) & [JSON Object Keys](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object)

[Original Source](https://community.zapier.com/code-webhooks-52/zapier-webhook-embed-discord-6048)